# How should I maintain a list of users within a MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, database-design, list

I have a users table, and each user has a unique `user_id`.  Each user also has a partner stored under `partner`.  A user will have only one partner at a time, but he will have multiple partners of the course of time.  I would like to maintain a list for every user of their past partners.  **How should I store such a list?**
I figured I would just have a column called `prior_partners` and be able to maintain a comma-separated list therein for each user.  Is that a possible solution?  Is it a good solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to create another table with user_id and partner names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably created a *partners* table that takes the id of both people, and a date. The latest date is the active partnership.

```
+----------+
| PARTNERS |
+----------+
| user_a   | (first partner)
+----------+
| user_b   | (second partner)
+----------+
| date     | (date the partnership began)
+----------+
```

This is a rather basic example. Depending on what exactly a partnership is, you may have other fields.

A history of partners would reflect as a series of rows:

```
Fizzbuzz Socks | Noke Shoes | Jan 23, 1983
StackOverflow  | GoogleDocs | Jan 29, 1992
Fizzbuzz Socks | Life Shoes | Nov 02, 1990
Fizzbuzz Socks | Sutt Shoes | Oct 18, 1995
```

From this we can see that Fizzbuzz had three partnerships in history, and the present partnership is with Sutt Shoes, started on Oct 18, 1995. For every new partnership, you would create a new record.

Comment: Jonathan, same question for you as I asked Kyle.

Comment: I think this works best for me.  Kyle's answer is noteworthy, and probably best for many applications, but this provides me with what I need and a little room to grow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using the power of the relational database to track this information.  I'd make another table called 'partners' or something similar, and have three columns: 'user_id_1', 'user_id_2', and 'start_date' (you can add an 'end_date' column for ease of querying if you like).

Then, when you have a partner change, just do an insert into this new table (and, if you've got an 'end_date' column, update those rows accordingly).  Then, when you want to pull the information from the table, just use a join with a subquery that gets the most current partner information and you'll always have updated and historical partnership data stored in your database.

Setting it up this way is a little more complicated on its face, but it will allow you to pull up MUCH more information over time about the relationships between people.

edit:

Your select query would be formatted something like this (and this is easier in mySQL if you do include the end_date field):

```
SELECT u.user_id, coalesce(p1.user_id1, p2.user_id2) as current_partner_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id1, max(user_id2) as user_id2
  FROM partnerships
  WHERE end_date IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_id1
) p1 on p1.user_id1 = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT max(user_id1) as user_id1, user_id2
  FROM partnerships
  WHERE end_date IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_id2
) p2 on p2.user_id2 = u.user_id
```

My primary area of expertise is MS SQL rather than mySQL, but I believe the above will get you the current partner for each user, along with that user.

Then, if you want to see the history of all partnerships for a given user, you'd write a query like this:

```
SELECT user_2 as partner_id, begin_date, end_date
FROM partnerships
WHERE user_1 = '{your user id of interest}'

UNION

SELECT user_1 as partner_id, begin_date, end_date
FROM partnerships
WHERE user_2 = '{your user id of interest}'

ORDER BY begin_date
```

This will get you a chronological recordset of partnerships for {your user id of interest}.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't I need to have as many columns in the partnerships table as there have been partners for any user?  So, a user with a history of 26 partners would require `user_id`, `partner_a`, `partner_b`, and so on thru `partner_z`?

Comment: No, that's the great thing about relational databases.  Instead of having one column per partner, you have one row per partner pair.  So in that case, you'd have 26 rows, each with user_id in one of the two person_id fields, and with partner_a, partner_b, etc. in the other partner_id field.  You'll want to use the begin_date field to track the date on which the partnership began, and (if you feel like it) use the end_date field to track the date on which the partnership ended.

Comment: I've added some specifics of the implementation as edits to my original reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the long run you're probably better off creating a separate table to manage this relationship, with a field referencing the partner and the user. And maybe some other field to indicate which relationship is active. The first reason I can think of is that it's much easier to query against fields in a table, than against values in a comma-separated text field.

Answer (score 0):

A comma-separated list is a very bad idea. It's too difficult to work with when trying to join back to the partners. Better to create a new table to hold the historical relationships.